# Uniformly convergence of $\sum \frac{x}{n}\sin(\sqrt{n^{2}+1}x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{x}{n}\sin(\sqrt{n^{2}+1}x)$ , where $x \in (0,\pi)$.

What can we say about uniformly convergence of series ?

I've tried to use Abel's summation. $A_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin(\sqrt{n^{2}+1}x)$, so $\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge 1}A_{n}\left(\frac{x}{n}-\frac{x}{n+1}\right) = \sum_{n \ge 1}A_{n}\frac{x}{n(n+1)}$. But don't know how can we estimate sum of $\sin(\sqrt{n^{2}+1}x)$. Any ideas?

Comment: Idea: $$\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{x}{n}\sin (\sqrt{n^2+1}\,x) = \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{x}{n}\sin (nx) + \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{x}{n}\bigl(\sin (\sqrt{n^2+1}\,x) - \sin (nx)\bigr)\,.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It often helps to approximate something complicated - like your $A_n$ - with something simpler. In this case, since $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ doesn't differ much from $n$, we can try to use $\sin (nx)$. The behaviour of

$$\sum_{n = 1}^N \sin (nx)$$

is well-known, and consequently Abel summation can be used to show that

$$\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{x}{n}\sin (nx)$$

converges uniformly on $(0,\pi)$. [It's essential that we have the factor $x$ outside the $\sin$, without that, we'd only have uniform convergence on $[\delta, 2\pi-\delta]$ for every $\delta \in (0,\pi]$, not on $(0,\pi)$.]

Then we must control the error we made by the approximation. Since $\sqrt{n^2+1} - n \sim \frac{1}{2n}$, we have

$$\biggl\lvert \frac{x}{n} \bigl(\sin (\sqrt{n^2+1}\,x) - \sin (nx)\bigr)\biggr\rvert \leqslant \frac{K}{n^2},$$

so the series of errors converges absolutely and uniformly on $(0,\pi)$. Overall, the uniform convergence of the original series follows.

Comment: Daniel, first of all, happy holidays.  Second, why restrict the UC to the open interval $(0,\pi)$ when we have uniform convergence on $[0,2\pi -\delta]$ for any $0<\delta\le 2\pi$.

Comment: @MarkViola First: thanks, I reciprocate. Second: $(0,\pi)$ is the interval specified in the question, so I took that. No deeper reason.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  Much appreciate both the sentiment and the quick reply. And (+1) for the well-written solution. -Mark